# How do i change the Rect Transform in Unity in a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the Width and, height in a Rect Transform. But i cant change it in my script. Does anybody know how to change it?

I found this and tried it but it didn't work

```
RectTransform rt = canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(700, 500);
```

I figured out how i could choose the position, but not the width and height.

Comment: It's possible that the code you provided may not be working because the canvas object you're trying to access is not correctly assigned in your script, or that the RectTransform component is not correctly assigned to the canvas object.

It's also possible that the sizeDelta is being overridden by some other script, or by the layout component you are using.

I would recommend checking if the canvas object is properly assigned and that the RectTransform component is correctly assigned to the canvas object in the inspector.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i have never dealt with changing the width of a Rect Transform but you can try changing the variable to something like
`public RectTransform rt`
then assigning the object to the variable. Or try
`[SerializeField] RectTransform rt;`
Although I'm not sure the variable would fix anything. Hope this helps!